# Async execution of void method with Hystrix

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, hystrix

I wonder how to execute a method without a return value asynchronous by using Hystrix. See the following example.

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    @HystrixCommand
    public void test() {
        // some code ...
    }
}
```

I want to invoke the `test()` method multiple times (fire and forget) and the command should be executed asynchronous. The method doesn't return anything. How can I do that?

**EDIT 1**

> so what is stopping you. You can execute a method which is backed by hystrix, even if it has no return value

This method is invoked multiple times at once. I don't want that the caller has to wait until the execution is finished before the method is invoked again.

Comment: so what is stopping you. You can execute a method which is backed by hystrix, even if it has no return value

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this:

```
@HystrixCommand
public Future<Object> test() {
    return new AsyncResult<Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object invoke() {
            // your code here
            doSomething();
            // just return null
            return null; 
        }
    };
}
```

See: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica#asynchronous-execution

Or, you can use without annotation:

```
new HystrixCommand<Object>(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("ExampleGroup")) {
    @Override
    protected Object run() throws Exception {
        doSomething();
        return null;
    }
}.queue();
```

See: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use#asynchronous-execution